make fails on a system without Qt
I made a modification to my project to recognize whether I'm building against GTK or Qt. I can build my project on the system where Qt is installed, but if there is no Qt it fails with:
g++: warning: @QT_CXXFLAGS@: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: error: @QT_CXXFLAGS@: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [Makefile:645: libdialogs_la-dialogs.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/igor/dbhandler_new/Debug/libdialogs'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:524: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/igor/dbhandler_new/Debug'
make: *** [Makefile:435: all] Error 2

My Makefile.am looks like this:
## Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in

QT_CXXFLAGS = @QT_CXXFLAGS@
QT_DIR = @QT_DIR@
QT_LIBS = @QT_LIBS@
QT_LRELEASE = @QT_LRELEASE@
QT_LUPDATE = @QT_LUPDATE@
QT_MOC = @QT_MOC@
QT_RCC = @QT_RCC@
QT_UIC = @QT_UIC@


lib_LTLIBRARIES =  \
        libdialogs.la

libdialogs_la_SOURCES =  \
# source files

libdialogs_la_CXXFLAGS = -I../../dbinterface \
        -I../../libfieldswindow \
        -I../../libshapeframework \
        -I../../libpropertypages \
        -I../../libpropertieshandlers \
        `pkg-config \
        --cflags \
        gtk+-3.0` \
        -I../../libhelpers \
        `wx-config \
        --cxxflags` \
        $(QT_CXXFLAGS)

libdialogs_la_LDFLAGS = -L../libsqlite \
        -L../libshapeframework \
        -L../dbinterface \
        -L../libfieldswindow \
        -L../libodbc \
        -L../libpostgres \
        -L../libpropertypages \
        -L../libhelpers \
        -L../libpropertieshandlers \
        -ldbinterface \
        -lsqlite_lib \
        -lodbc_lib \
        -lshapeframework \
        -lhelpers \
        -lfieldswindow \
        -lpropertypages \
        -lpropertieshandlers \
        -lpostgres \
        `wx-config \
        --libs` $(QT_LIBS)

And I am calling AX_HAVE_QT() in the configure.ac.
My understanding is that if the Qt is not present those variables will be empty. And it will be just extra spaces in the Makefile.
What am I missing?

This ...
QT_CXXFLAGS = @QT_CXXFLAGS@
QT_DIR = @QT_DIR@
QT_LIBS = @QT_LIBS@
QT_LRELEASE = @QT_LRELEASE@
QT_LUPDATE = @QT_LUPDATE@
QT_MOC = @QT_MOC@
QT_RCC = @QT_RCC@
QT_UIC = @QT_UIC@

... is unneeded. Automake will do that for you when it generates Makefile.in.  In Automake.am you just use Autoconf output variables as make variables.
The actual problem appears to be that those are not being defined as output variables in the event that you have a non-Qt build, so the substitution tokens (@QT_CXXFLAGS@, etc.) are not being replaced in that case.  The AX_HAVE_QT macro I think you're using does set them even if it doesn't find Qt, so I think the issue must be that you're using that only under some circumstances, not all.
In that case, you have two main alternatives:

make sure to run AX_HAVE_QT under all circumstances, even though you may not always perform a Qt build, OR
if you choose not to run AX_HAVE_QT under some circumstances, then in those cases manually AC_SUBST() empty values for all those variables. Or at least for those among them that you actually use.

